# nodejs execute scp showing progress in console

Tags: node.js, scp, spawn

I'm using the scp command in a node application to transfer a file to a server;
I've not been able to show in console the progress while transferring, as "scp" normally does if you use it in the shell manually;
here is my code:

```
//require system modules
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

console.log("copy begins...");

var executor = spawn("scp", ["-r", ".tmp/app.tar.gz", "user@server:/home/user"]);

executor.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

executor.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

executor.stdout.on('end', function(data) {
    console.log("copied");
});

executor.on('close', function(code) {
    if (code !== 0) {
        console.log('Failed: ' + code);
    }
});
```

This just logs in the console "copy begins..." and "copied", but nothing else;
is it possible to get the output of the scp command during its execution and send it to the console?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also struggling with the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

`scp` only outputs what it calls the "progress meter" if its standard output is a TTY:

```
$ scp localhost:/etc/passwd . 
passwd                                        100% 5253     5.1KB/s   00:00    
$ scp localhost:/etc/passwd . | cat
$
```

So your program would have to arrange for the standard output of the scp process to be a TTY or PTY (pseudo-tty).

I'm not a node programmer so I can't provide you with a complete example of how to do that. You could try running `scp` through the `expect` program. It's capable of allocating PTYs and running child processes through them. Alternately, it appears that node has a 'tty' module which might be able to do what you want. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122282/how-do-i-open-a-terminal-application-from-node-js) discusses running `vim` from node through a tty; you might be able to use the same approach.

Comment: Ok, now I understand more; node js have a core module for tty; unfortunally I've not been able until now to get the desired result...