# how to start a text editor from node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to open a unix text editor (`nano` in this case) by issuing following command in a Node.js script:

```
  if (process.argv[2] === 'edit') {
    require('child_process').spawn("sudo", ["nano", dbFile], {
      stdio: 'inherit'
    });
    process.exit(); // try to block here in order not to execute rest of code in this file
  }
```

This opens up `nano`, but both the text is weird and it doesn't let me write anything.

Comment: Really `("nano " + dbFile).split(' ')` should be `["nano", dbFile]`.

Comment: you are right, but they gives the same result in this case. I'll update question accordingly.

Comment: you might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122282/how-do-i-open-a-terminal-application-from-node-js, it's vi but the accepted answer talks about problems you may run into. Like having to capture your input from the parent node process and piping the stream into your nano child process.

Answer (score 1):

I changed it a bit. Added an event listener on `data` on the process you spawned.

```
var dbFile = 'lol.js';
var editorSpawn = require('child_process').spawn("nano", [dbFile], {
  stdio: 'inherit',
  detached: true
});

editorSpawn.on('data', function(data){
  process.stdout.pipe(data);
});
```

inside of the `data` listener, `process.stdout.pipe` is streaming the output of nano to the terminal.

added my own variables and removed `sudo` as it was giving me errors. you should be able to apply this to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pty.js`:

You might want to put the standard input into [raw mode](http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_tty_setrawmode_mode). This way all the key strokes will be reported as a data event. Otherwise you only get lines (for every press of the `return` key).

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);      

var pty = require('pty.js');

var nano = pty.spawn('nano', [], {
   name: 'xterm-color',
   cols: process.stdout.columns,
   rows: process.stdout.rows,
   cwd: '.',
   env: process.env
});

nano.pipe(process.stdout);
process.stdin.pipe(nano);

nano.on('close', function () {
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I continued where @Sgnl's answer left off.

```
const { exit } = require("process");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const openConfigWithNano = async (pathToConfig) => {
  var nano = spawn("nano", [pathToConfig], {
    stdio: "inherit",
    detached: true,
  });

  nano.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Failed to start nano: ");
    console.error(err);
  });

  nano.on("data", function (data) {
    process.stdout.pipe(data);
  });
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    nano.on("close", resolve);
  });
  exit();
};
```

awaiting the "close" event allows to stop the parent process. I got the solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025854/12753573

Comment: It doesn't work. It has a syntax error `(data: any)` and it doesn't work after fixing it. Can you run this code?

Comment: @ceremcem now that I fixed the syntax error, I can run this code. Note that in order for the function to do anything you need to call it.

Comment: It doesn't work on my side, whole .js process just starts and then terminates. Maybe I need to understand the code and then change according to my needs. Thanks though.