# Execute commands with node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process

[image]I want to run commands like `vim` with node.js. I tried it with `require('child_process').exec` but the problem is that the output is done with `console.log()`.

Is there a possibility to execute `vim` within node.js?

Comment: what exaclty is your problem?
you can read the output stream of your child process, if this is what you need

Comment: @NickD I have just updated the post. There is an example now.

Comment: have you tried  `process.stdout.write();`   because `console.log();`  adds a newline at the end, and `process.stdout.write()` does not

Comment: @jmugz3 Tried it and yes, indeed, at least the last line is now removed but `vim` still does not work and `ls` is still separated with a new line. Also colors of my .bash_profile do not work.

Comment: for the colors, you have to add that to your node environment. Otherwise, it will just use its default, not your default.

Comment: this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122282/how-do-i-open-a-terminal-application-from-node-js).

Comment: @jmugz3 thanks for the submission. It is working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jmugz3 I found out that the question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122282/how-do-i-open-a-terminal-application-from-node-js). The complete solution can be found there.