# How can I do the same sort of thing as git editor spawning in node?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to spawn an editor in the middle of a program written in Node.js, let the user edit files in the directory opened in the editor, and return control to the program once the new editor instance is closed.

I would imagine I can do this with [child_process.spawnSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options).

Are there any example packages I can look at on npm which do this?

Comment: Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17110285/224334

Comment: Yep, does the trick. Thanks! Should I delete this question since it's already answered (couldn't find it when I looked). Or maybe submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at another StackOverflow answer: [on opening a EDITOR from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17110285/224334) and dealing with the TTY.

(Also consider using `GIT_EDITOR` end variable in addition to just `EDITOR` :)