# how to invoke vim in NPM scripts?

Tags: node.js, vim, npm, command-line-interface

[image]

If I run `npm run vim` in terminal, what will happen is my terminal will stay in a frozen status.

So, how can I invoke vim in NPM scripts correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122282/how-do-i-open-a-terminal-application-from-node-js

Comment: @sudo bangbang, thanks, it's helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open a terminal application from node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122282/how-do-i-open-a-terminal-application-from-node-js)

Comment: What's your npm version and OS? For me, npm 3.10.10 scripts  can invoke vim correctly in Win7 and Centos7 at least.

Comment: NPM 5.10.0 on win7